# Editing visual states of rich text block (selected text color)

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

Is there a way to change the default color of the selected text of a rich text block in xaml?

I checked themeresources and the generic xaml files in the kits/design folder and didn't see any brushes for selected text to override. I'm sure I can hook into the selectionchanged event, but I'd prefer to just set it up in xaml.

The default color is purple so it's being set somewhere I just can't find it.

This has got to be the most difficult control to work with in windows store apps, everything about it has been a battle!

Comment: Don't have Win store app environment available right now, but does `RichTextBox` has a `SelectionBrush` property (like `TextBox`)?

Comment: Sadly no, and richtextblock is a sealed class and you cannot override its default control template with a custom template either.